# how to listen to browser history events in Dart

Tags: dart

I could not make the code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12115784/1224600) work :(

```
window.on.popState.add((_) => showPage());
```

`Breaking on exception: Class 'Events' has no instance getter 'popState'.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use :

```dart
window.onPopState.listen((_) => showPage());
```